# How to delete specific line in text file?

Tags: python, file

I'm making a joke program that has a text file storing jokes. On program load, it grabs all the lines from the file and assigns them to a jokes list  Everything but the remove joke function is working. Whenever you call remove joke, it ends up re-writing every line in the text file to an empty string instead of the selected line

When running this function, it does remove the joke from the jokes list properly

```
def remove_joke():
    for i in range(len(jokes)):
        print(f"{i}\t{jokes[i]}")
    
    remove_index = int(input("Enter the number of the joke you want to remove:\t"))

    with open("jokes.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("jokes.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
            if line == jokes[remove_index]:
                f.write("")
    jokes.remove(jokes[remove_index])
```

Comment: `f.write()` rewrites the whole text file, making it blank

Comment: Does `jokes[remove_index]` contain a trailing `\n`?

Comment: @ThePilotDude that is not correct. `f.write(...)` writes its argument to the file at the current file pointer location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
            if line == jokes[remove_index]:
                f.write("")
```

you want:

```
            if line != jokes[remove_index]:
                f.write(line+'\n')
```

Or even:

```
            if line != jokes[remove_index]:
                print(line, file=f)
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you, that makes way more sense now. I'll mark it solved once the timer allows me to :)